# How to set spark setcheckpointdir in google cloud?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, hdfs, google-cloud-storage

I have been using my standalone spark/hadoop cluster. 
To do more complex jobs, I am trying to use GCP for submitting my pyspark codes.

Yes, I am a GCP newbie.

The problem is that "google storage" is not much cooperating with Spark. 
I am still learning what "google bucket" is. But, at the moment, "google bucket" seems to be a piece of XXXX.

====

What I like to do is the following:

1. I like to make three directories (buckets?!):

`gs://myinput/`

`gs://myoutput/`

`gs://mytemp/`

2. then, read my input data from `gs://myinput/a.input`
3. then, set the check point dir such as 
   `sc.setCheckpointDir("gs://mytemp")`
4. finally, write the result, such as : 
   `with open("gs://myoutput/output.pickle",'wb') as f: pickle.dump(myresult,f)
   f.close()`

====

As you can guess, if I change `gs://` to `hdfs://`, every code line will work flawlessly in Spark/Hadoop cluster.

But, in the GCP Dataproc, I can only pass the first input section.

So ... is GCP not much ready for PySpark users?

====

Thanks.

Comment: Self answers : The bucket itself cannot be a `CheckpointDir`. Hence, cp a dummy to a subdirectory, such as `gsutil cp dummy.txt gs://anybucket/TEMP/`. Then, use the `gs://anybucket/TEMP` dir for the Checkpoint.